# Can I add a small stud on top of a plaster wall?

Tags: drywall, plaster

I am covering an old room that has ugly wavy, bumpy, stylized plaster walls. I've looked into all of the options to remove the bumps and it will be simpler to cover it with wallboard.

The issue: One wall in the room has a 2 inch jog in it. Meaning, the right half of the room is 2 inches deeper than the left half.

I'm wondering if I can screw "surface studs" on top of the plaster wall inline with the studs behind the wall to line it up with the left half? Adding those "surface studs" would even out the full length of that wall for a single smooth surface.
Does anyone see an issue with this? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: I would pull the plaster out and sister some new studs to the existing ones out the 2+ inches once the plaster is removed. This will make adjusting the electrical outlets easier. The added bonus of adding sister studs would be strength and less chance of imperfections in the plaster causing the wall to bow.

Comment: Ugh... I'd really rather not deal with pulling the plaster down. That's my real motivation to just cover it. 120 yr old house... no outlets on that wall and not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. I'd use 4" gold construction screws every 24" or so. If this results in a wavy plane, simply insert shims behind the studs near screws where needed.

I would remove the corner bead (if present) at the jog and tape to just the plaster. This will help eliminate the "ski jump" that's often present at outside corners, especially once you add another layer of tape.